# Error Installing ESRI ArcGIS Server Java Web ADF Plug-in in Netbeans 7.x

Tags: arcgis, netbeans-7, esri, netbeans-plugins

I am very new to GIS. I wanted to use ESRI ArcGIS Server Java Web ADF Plug-in in Netbeans 7.0.1
But when I followed the installation guide/instruction, it failed to install because of some dependency version mismatch.

It shows ...........................

Some plugins require plugin Editor Library to be installed.
The plugin Editor Library is requested in version >= 1.9.22.1 (release version 1) but only 3.9.1.13.10 (of release version different from 1) was found. The following plugin is affected: ******ESRI ArcGIS Java ADF web controls NetBeans Module.

[image: Snapshot of the error]

Any Suggestion to overcome this ??

FYI I am using Windows 7 64bit with 64bit JVM and Netbeans.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The NetBeans plugin was for ADF developers, and the ADF has been deprecated, and 10.1 will be the last release of it.[here is the link of the question asked on their official forum](http://forums.arcgis.com/threads/45226-Installing-Netbeans-plugin)
beside this , as you are not a new member , but i want to tell you that atleast google them once before asking such type of simple question.I hope you are not child enough and have read the [faqs](https://stackoverflow.com/faq) as well.
I am not the one who down voted you but i guess this has been down voted because of your this silly attitude
Goodluck

Comment: And please do accept the answer, if you think it is enough helpful for you